# 64bit prcessor with 32bit operating system program compatibilities?

Tags: python, linux

on 64bit processors.
with 32bit operating system 
all programs works fine ?

like suppose all python 32bit installation programs works fine ? or there are any issues found?

a program or software developed on 32bit operating system & 32bit processor 
installed on 32bit operating system and 64bit processor 
does it work well or any issues?

why i am asking this, bec these days on market all 64bit processor os computers coming and mostly sold. there is no choice also for us..if i want to buy a i5processor computer..

Comment: x86-64 processors can run x86-32 code natively, so your 32bit OS and applications will run the same.

Answer (score 3):

> on 64bit processors. with 32bit
>   operating system all programs works
>   fine ?

Yes.

> like suppose all python 32bit
>   installation programs works fine ? or
>   there are any issues found?

No issues.

> a program or software developed on
>   32bit operating system & 32bit
>   processor installed on 32bit operating
>   system and 64bit processor does it
>   work well or any issues?

Yes.

> why i am asking this, bec these days
>   on market all 64bit processor os
>   computers coming and mostly sold.
>   there is no choice also for us..if i
>   want to buy a i5processor computer..

If you have say a 64bit edition of Windows, there is the [64bit version of Pyth](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7/)on available.

The advantage for you is that you can have more RAM (> 4GB) and thus access large amounts of data.

The difference between 32bit and 64bit in case of Python should not worry you at all. Python is a high level language, the process architecture and the difference in size of data types is not your concern.

Comment: Aren't pointers 8 bytes long in 64-bit CPython?  It would seem that until memories grow so that we are using more than 32 or 33 bits of address space (i.e. more than 4 or 8 GB available) that we are really wasting data cache space with bloated half-way useless 8-byte pointers.   I plan on running 32 bit Python on my 64 bit machine until I really really think I need >2GB in a user process.

Comment: @K. Brafford: After much comparison, and low level programming I can tell you this definitive answer. The only thing 64bit guarantees is more virtual address space to each process. For now they perform the same, and 64bit software is less well supported. In the distant future, 64bit will be better supported, and perform better. This is not the case at the moment. There are exceptions, but they're nitpicking.

Answer (score 0):

Should be fine. X64 processors run x32 code natively. My dev PC is x64 but it has run a 32 bit OS and code with no problems whatsoever for 4 or so years.

Similarly, it should run 16 bit (8086) code and operating systems just fine!

Comment: It should run them, but you shouldn't ;)

Comment: True, but the point is that it is still there, and unless Intel break something, it will continue for at least the next few generations of replacements.

Comment: windows 3.11 Python available? Should I dust of my installation diskettes ;)

Comment: @Tony Veijalainen: Hehe, 3.11 support was dropped in python 2.2 i think.